# How to show mysql data in html using python

Tags: python, html, mysql-python, mysql-connector, pyscript

I was given a task to create a database and display the information there in a simple html page, with the help of python. Can you help me understand how it is done?

I tried to write py-script in html, but then import mysql.connector doesn't work. Besides py-script, are there any other options to do the task?

Comment: I am not aware of a MySQL driver that will run inside a web browser because MySQL does not support HTTP requests by itself. My suggestion is to have PyScript interact with a web server that interfaces with MySQL. Your PyScript will make HTTP REST calls to the web server.

Comment: You may want to look at [the Datasette project](https://datasette.io/). You can use Datasette with MySQL by mirroring the database see [here in the documentation](https://docs.datasette.io/en/0.28/ecosystem.html). After that mirroring, maybe you can use DatasetteLite, which can run entirely in the browser? For more on DatasetteLite,  search 'Lite' [here on the main Datasette page](https://datasette.io/).